# Keyword search in ElasticSearch with no regards to the schema

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use ElasticSearch to do keyword searches, exactly like in a search engine?

Let me rephrase:

As far as I understand, an ElasticSearch term query requires to specify in which field(s?) to search for keywords.
Given the fact that ElasticSearch can be "schemaless", I wish I could declare a query than can search for keywords in any field.

Is there a syntax for that?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the behavior provided by the `_all`-field, which happens to be on by default:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html

Here's a runnable example: https://www.found.no/play/gist/14688f48c75b9931272b

```
export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"foo":"bar"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"something_else":"foo bar"}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": {
                "query": "bar"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```